# MATLAB Cross Correlation Own code

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I am trying to understand code written by my predecessor. Rather than using a xcorr in MATLAB, she did the following. Apparently this seems to working. I would really appreciate if someone could explain, what is happening here. She is saying the pattern is symmetric by calculating the variable sym below, in the code below.

```
close all hidden

t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
x = sin(t)
plot(x,'k')
mu = mean(x)
sigma = std(x)

y = (x-mu)/(sigma);
hold on
plot(y,'r')

yrev = y(end:-1:1);
hold on 
plot(yrev)
hold on
sym = sum(y.*yrev/length(y))
plot(y.*yrev/length(y),'r*')
```

Comment: You mean even she cannot explain what she has done!? This is the way of calculating [covariance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html) when having a single vector as input (hence variance). Check the formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sym` is the [normalised cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) between y and the reverse of y.

- If `sym` is close to one, y is a symmetric function.
- If `sym` is close to zero, y is an asymmetric function
- If `sym` is close to minus one, y is a anti-symmetric function

**EDIT**: relation with `xcorr`

You would obtain the same result if you calculate `sym` as follows:

```
sym = xcorr(y, yrev, 0, 'coeff')
```

Comment: your answer does not explain why this outcome is not consistent with the result of `xcorr`?

Comment: @NKN I edited my answer to incorporate your comment.

Comment: cool(+1), the lag is 0 and `coeff`  Normalizes the sequence so that the autocorrelations at zero lag equal 1.

Comment: `sym` will equal 1 if and only if `y` is an exact symmetric function

Comment: @m7913d would appreciate more clarification. y is the area under curve. Dot product with its reverse, is giving me convolution not correlation. And finally why one should divide by length

Comment: Dot product with its reverse is indeed a convolution of the signal with itself, but it is also a correlation between the signal and the reverse of the signal. You should divide by length and standard deviation, to obtain a normalised value between -1 and 1. See also the link to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) in the answer.